# Problema con Memoria Dinamica en QT

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con las memorias dinámicas. Tengo este header, el cual mando a llamar con mi `main.cpp`, no me opera el *void de Multiplicar*, y el de *Sumar* porque se detiene el proceso.

No sé mucho de cómo reservar memoria y cómo liberarla, y por lo que he sabido creo no la libera, ya que a veces ejecuta el código pero mi programa termina ciclado.

```
#ifndef MATRICES
#define MATRICES
#include <stdio.h>

class cMatriz{
public:                                            //declarar directivas publicas
    cMatriz(void){}                              //declarar constructor vacio
    cMatriz(int Filas_, int Columnas_){
        Filas = Filas_;
        Columnas = Columnas_;

    //  Constructor  Matriz
    Matriz=new double*[Filas];                  //Reserva memoria para las filas
         for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            Matriz[i]=new double[Columnas];         //Reserva memoria para las columas de cada fila
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++)                  //Coloca ceros
                Matriz[i][j]=0.0;
            }

    }

    //Destructor
   ~cMatriz(void){
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++)                        //Libera memoria para las columnas de cada fila
            delete Matriz[i];
        delete Matriz;                              //Libera memoria de las filas
    }

    void GuardaEn(int i, int j, double Valor){
        Matriz[i][j]=Valor;
    }

    void Imprime(void){                             //Imprime la matriz
        printf("\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++)
                 printf("%f\t",Matriz[i][j]);
                 printf("\n");
            }
    }

    void Ceros(void){                               //Rellena la matriz con ceros
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++)
                 Matriz[i][j]=0.0;
            }
    }

    void Unos(void){                                //Rellena la matriz con unos
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++)
                 Matriz[i][j]=1.0;
            }
    }

    void Identidad(void){                           //Crea la matriz identidad
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                 Matriz[i][j]=( i == j ? 1.0 : 0.0);

            }
            }
    }

     void Llenar(void){                                 //Llenar matriz a travez de teclado
         for  (i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for  (j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                 printf("Ingrese la posicion %d", i+1);
                 printf("%d ", j+1);
                 printf(" de la Matriz\t");
                 scanf("%lf",&Matriz[i][j]);
            }
         }
     }

     void Aleatoria(void){                                 //Llenar matriz aleatoriamente
         for  (i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for  (j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                Matriz[i][j] = rand() % 30;
            }
         }
     }


    void MulEscal(void){                            //Multilicacion por un Escalar
        //k=0;
        printf("Ingrese el escalar a multiplicar. ");
        scanf("%d",&k);
        for  (i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for  (j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                 Matriz[i][j]=Matriz[i][j]*k;
            }
         }
    }

    void Transpuesta(cMatriz A){                                 //Calcular transpuesta
        for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                Matriz[i][j]=0;
                GuardaEn(i ,j , A.Elemento(j,i));
            }
        }
    }

    void Suma(cMatriz A, cMatriz B){                //Suma de matrices
            for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
                for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++){
                    GuardaEn(i ,j , A.Elemento(i,j) + B.Elemento(i,j));
                }
            }
    }

    void Multiplicar(cMatriz A, cMatriz B){                //Multiplicacion de matrices

        for(i=0;i<2;i++){                                   //se puso val de 2, para cambiar rangos asi como activar el condicional de filas=columnas hay que activar en el main las variables
            for(j=0;j<2;j++){
                Matriz[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<2;k++){
                    GuardaEn(i ,j ,( Matriz[i][j] +( A.Elemento(i,k)*B.Elemento(k,j))));
                }

            }
        }

    }

    double Elemento(int Fila, int Columna){
        return Matriz[Fila][Columna];
    }

private:
    int i, j, k;
    int Filas, Columnas;
    double **Matriz;                                // donde **Matriz es igual a Matriz[][]
};


#endif // MATRICES
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se crea con `new[]` se debe liberar con `delete[]`. Si usas `delete` acabas con fugas de memoria. En tu caso el código del destructor está mal:

```
//  Constructor  Matriz
Matriz=new double*[Filas];
for(i=0;i<Filas;i++){
  Matriz[i]=new double[Columnas];
  for(j=0;j<Columnas;j++)
    Matriz[i][j]=0.0;
}

//Destructor
for(i=0;i<Filas;i++)
  delete Matriz[i];
delete Matriz;
```

Lo correcto sería lo siguiente:

```
//Destructor
for(i=0;i<Filas;i++)
  delete[] Matriz[i];
delete[] Matriz;
```

En cuanto a lo que comentas del error te recomiendo leer detenidamente tu pregunta y corregirla, ya que no se termina de entender el problema.

Además, esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Qt (da igual que el main use Qt o que compiles desde QtCreator si no enlazas con ninguna librería de Qt), por lo que te recomendaría eliminar dicha etiqueta junto con todas las referencias a Qt.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, @eferion, en efecto el problema ha cesado, un saludo.